# How can I clear one variable (List Of Array Lists), without unintentionally clearing another?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, arraylist

To be clear, I have **one 3D ArrayList** which I intend to use: **to hold several 2D ArrayLists.**

3D ArrayList (When I say 3D ArrayList, this is what I'm referring to):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> main_Functions = new ArrayList<>();
```

2D ArrayList (When I say 2D ArrayList, this is what I'm referring to):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> localValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

But after adding each 2D ArrayList, I intend to *clear* the variable holding the original 2D ArrayList. So old information doesn't interfere with newly added information etc. But after I clear the variable holding the original 2D ArrayList (what was added to the 3D ArrayList), the **data added to the 3D ArrayList is erased.**

My code is below:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> localValues = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> main_Functions = new ArrayList<>();

           if (arrayListNotEmpty(localValues)) {
                main_Functions.add(localValues);
                localValues.clear();
          }
```

**How can I fix this?** 
*so information added to the 3D ArrayList, remains upon the 2D ArrayList's clearing*?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 3D ArrayList.

Comment: That's what I've used above "ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> main_Functions ". Unless that's called something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation is basically this: (I've removed one level of `ArrayList`s to make it clearer)

```
ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outer = new ArrayList<>();

inner.add("Hello World!");
outer.add(inner);
System.out.println(outer.get(0)); // prints [Hello World!]
inner.clear();
System.out.println(outer.get(0)); // prints [] i.e. an empty list
```

Or, even simpler:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("Hello World!");

ArrayList<String> b = a;

System.out.println(b); // prints [Hello World!]
a.clear();
System.out.println(b); // prints []
```

This is because `a` and `b` do not contain `ArrayList`s. In Java, if we say a variable holds an ArrayList, what we actually mean is it holds a *reference* to an ArrayList.

In other words, what `a` actually contains is "ArrayList #1234" or something like that. `b` also contains "ArrayList #1234". The line `a.clear()` clears ArrayList #1234, and the line `System.out.println(b);` prints the contents of ArrayList #1234 (which we just cleared).

Instead, you can create a new ArrayList whenever you want to copy it.

For example, instead of

```
main_Functions.add(localValues);
```

you could do something like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> localValues_copy = new ArrayList<>(localValues);
main_Functions.add(localValues_copy);
```

or shortened:

```
main_Functions.add(new ArrayList<>(localValues));
```

this will add a reference to a brand new ArrayList to your "3D ArrayList", instead of adding a reference to the same one `localValues` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<String>> localValues = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> localValuesCopy = new ArrayList<>(localValues);

localValues.clear();// won't affect main_Functions

List<List<List<String>>> main_Functions = new ArrayList<>();
main_Functions.add(localValuesCopy);
```

By creating a **copy** of your `localValues` list, the data is duplicated and clearing it won't affect this new data.

Although I don't understand why you would want to clear the `localValues` list, clearing `localValues` won't change the `main_Functions` list.

Comment: Is it possible to continue to use ArrayLists?

Comment: @FilmVersion, it is but Batman's answer above of using an interface `List` is the right way of doing it.

Comment: @FilmVersion, `ArrayList` is an **implementation** of the `List` interface.

Comment: I'm wanting to add localValues to main_Functions, not make it equal to localValues. How can I modify the above, to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not making them equal, it **does** add `localValues` to `main_Functions`

Comment: @BruceWayne, I think he meant concat the previous and new Lists, not initialize it again with the new values.

Comment: That's what I meant by **3D ArrayList**, so I could **hold several 2D ArrayLists**. E.g. add more than one to the 3D ArrayList. And **perform a .get command to access them** etc.

Comment: @FilmVersion, I've updated the answer, clearing `localValues` won't affect your `main_Functions` list anymore.